# Share virtual machine between Genymotion and Android AVD Manager?

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion, avd-manager

I've installed Genymotion and configure it to use the SDK folder from Android SDK. (In preferences, ADB -> Use custom Android SDK tools, and select `/Users/XXX/Library/Android/sdk`)

But when I open both Genymotion and Android AVD manager, it can't see the same virtual machine created in each other:

[image: AVD Manager showing Nexus 5X API 24 only]

[image: Genymotion showing Nexus 4 API 19 only]

Is there a way to share the virtual machine, without taking extra disk spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genymotion and the Android emulator for Android SDK can not interoperate because the used virtualization system is totally different:

**Android Emulator from SDK** uses an **QEMU 2** based emulator for running the emulator images.

**Genymotion** uses **VirtualBox** emulator as the underlying virtualization system. As VirtualBox only supports x86 emulation for example ARMv7/ARMv8 based emulator do not exist for Genymotion.

Effectively this means that the emulated devices are slightly different. For example they are different regarding the emulated devices (e.g. graphics chip) and the used file formats.
As different devices require different drivers converting an emulator image from one system to another is also not that easy.